# Adding two image gallery messes eachother

Tags: javascript, html

I got an image gallery which includes some images under one big, The big one is one of the underneath ones. However, when I add a new image gallery this overwrites the old one and when I click on those pictures it changes the first gallery images which I don't want. I think there some error in my javascript code, and it's targetting all of my galleries, can I make it so it only target the clicked image?
Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u8pbtLra/

And here is the code

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var xSlides = slides.length;
  alert(xSlides);
  var slideIndexes = [0,1,0];
  alert(slideIndexes);
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="container2">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class = "bb" style="background-image:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328);"></div> 
    <!-- The above div is the problem -->
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328"  onclick="currentSlide(1)"  width="100%" alt="text">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" width="100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want to do. You have 3 pictures in your fiddle: 1 big and 2 small below. When you click on the small cat, the big man is replaced by the cat. What do you want exactly?

Comment: Your second slideshow is also called `mySlides`, so your code doesn't really know which slides belong to which slideshow. The easiest solution is to rename the second slideshow to `mySlidesTwo`, and rewrite your code so that it knows which slideshow is being targeted.

Comment: true but I cant do that

Comment: There you have my issue @Kokodoko

Comment: I need to be able to add multiple gallerys without chaning their class

Comment: In that case you first have to check how many slideshows there are using `document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides").length`, and then, you create an array that keeps track of the current slide for each separate slideshow, for example: `let slideIndexes = [0,1,0]`. This means that the first slideshow is at 0, the second is at 1, and the third slideshow is at 0

Comment: And then, the `showSlides()` function needs to know which slideshow to target, for example: `function showSlides(0, 1)` will show slide 1 in slideshow 0

Comment: I dont understand how I implent the array in the script tho, and if i change the showSlides fnction to 0,1 the currentslide gets undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code is that the same class is used for both galleries. If you don't want to rename the classes you can pass `this` to your click handler and then find the parent element. You can then pass the parent element to `showSlides` function to get the decedent slides.

*There are ways to improve the code but I kept it as presented.*

See this example:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
wrappers.forEach(function(el) {
  showSlides(slideIndex, el);
});



// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(el, n) {
  // Get the wrapper element and pass it as a variable to showSlides
  let wrapper = el.closest(".wrapper");
  showSlides(slideIndex = n, wrapper);
}

function showSlides(n, wrapper) {
  var i;
  // find only the slides and dot that are decedents of current wrapper
  var slides = wrapper.querySelectorAll(".mySlides");
  var dots = wrapper.querySelectorAll(".demo");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.container3 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.bb {
  height: 100px;
  background: center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- add wrapper class -->
<div class="container3 wrapper">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="bb" style="background-image:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328);"></div>
    <!-- The above div is the problem -->
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <!-- pass this to handler -->
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328" onclick="currentSlide(this,1)" width="100%" alt="text">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <!-- pass this to handler -->
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" width="100%" onclick="currentSlide(this, 2)" alt="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- add wrapper class -->
<div class="container2 wrapper">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="bb" style="background-image:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328);"></div>
    <!-- The above div is the problem -->
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <!-- pass this to handler -->
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328" onclick="currentSlide(this,1)" width="100%" alt="text">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <!-- pass this to handler -->
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" width="100%" onclick="currentSlide(this, 2)" alt="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow thanks alot mate, il look into it so I understand it better!:)